# How can a single participant update all scores for iOS 7 Game Center turn-based matches?

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center

I understand that in iOS 7 the participant who ends a turn-based match may report scores for all participants (no longer just her own score). To this end he can call [`endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:scores:achievements:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKTurnBasedMatch/endMatchInTurnWithMatchData%3ascores%3aachievements%3acompletionHandler%3a).

But how can she initialize `scores` when [`GKScore`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)'s `playerId` is read-only (and the value will always correspond to the identifier of the local player?)

Perhaps it is intended that `scores` is initialized with [`loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLeaderboard/loadScoresWithCompletionHandler%3a), but how would this cover cases where a participant  (who is not the local player) receives his first score (i.e. has no previous entry in leaderboard)?

In short, is there a good sample for updating of all scores by a single participant?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this can be achieved using [`initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:forPlayer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKScore/initWithLeaderboardIdentifier%3aforPlayer%3a) (available in iOS 7.0 and later).